A question on unit norm elements of $\ell^2 \setminus \bigcup_{0<p<2 }\ell^p$
Let  $A\subset \ell^2$  consist of  all  $x\in \ell^2$  with $|x|_2=1$ which  does not  belong to any $\ell^p$  for  all  $0<p<2$.
Note that $A$ is  non-empty with a  Baire category  argument.
I  am  interested in (somewhat) distribution and configuration of  $A$ and its complement in the  unit  sphere $S$ of  $\ell^2$.
Note that $S\setminus A$ is  path connected.

Is $S\setminus A$ a  contractible  space?


What can  be  said about connected  components of $A$? In particular  can one  find at least one  non constant  curve?

Note:  I was  thinking to a possible  density of  $A$ in the  sphere, or to a possible  measure of  $A$ as  a  subset of sphere. Note  that  density  of a  subset $A$ at a point $p$ of  a  metric  space  with measure $\mu$ is the  limit $\frac{\mu(A\cap B_\epsilon)}{\mu (B_{\epsilon})}$  as $\epsilon$  goes to 0.  ($B_\epsilon$ is the  ball  around $p$).
But  I realized that the measure theory on  infinite  Banach  spaces is a technical matter:
What is known about the Gaussian measure of the unit ball in a Hilbert Space?
What is the 'right' definition of zero measure subsets of Banach spaces?
Invariant probability on a unit ball of a Banach space
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75932/measure-on-hilbert-space

$A$ is dense, also by Baire category. (Or, really, it’s just the unit sphere minus a proper subspace. Of course it’s dense.)

@DavidGao  Obviously both  $A$  and  $S\setminus A$ are  dense.  I do not get  what  do you meant?

I thought your note meant you’re thinking about asking whether $A$ is dense? I suppose I was mistaken.

@DavidGao No  the  density is  obvious but the  2  items  I mentioned  is  my  main  questions.

@DavidGao  Oh I get  what  you  say. By  density  I  meant  some  thing as  follows: Let A  is  a  subset of  of  topological  measur  space  the  density of  A at a  point p is the  limit $\frac{\mu (A\cap U)}{\mu(U)}$  where U  shrink  to p  among  open neighborhoods of  p

So  I  would  need  to  a kind  of  measure!

@DavidGao  This  is  the  reason that I  did not  include the  Note part into the  main question.  If  I  have  an obvious  measure then  I would  ask what  can be  said about the  measure of  A or  its  complement

Ah, I see what you meant. You should probably clarify that in the question. (Or just remove the note altogether if it’s not important anyway.) It is a bit confusing as it seems like you’re asking whether $A$ is dense.

@DavidGao  Ok  I  add a  link of  density to  note.

For your second question, read Chapter 6 in the book of Benyamini and Lindenstrauss for concepts of null sets and their uses.

@BillJohnson Thank you very much  Prof. Johnson for your attention

@BillJohnson  What  can  be  said  about the  topological or Hausdorff dimension of A and  its  complement?

@BillJohnson   BTW  what  was  the  title  of the  book  you  mentioned? I  did not  find  a book in this  list  of the  following wikipedia coauthored by Benyamini

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joram_Lindenstrauss

The book is in the list on Wikipedia:   Geometric nonlinear functional analysis (with Yoav Benyamini). Colloquium publications, 48. American Mathematical Society, 2000.

Umm, $A$ is path-connected and it is fairly simple -- just change the coordinates one by one. Say we want to go from $u\in A$ to $v\in A$. On $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ change linearly $u_1$ to $v_1$, then on $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}]$ change linearly $u_2$ to $v_2$ and so on. The only slight issue is that we are leaving the sphere, but just consider $v(t) = u(t)/||u(t)||$, then $v(0) = u, v(1) = v$, and $v(t)\notin \ell^p$ for all $0 < p < 2$ and all $0\le t < 1$ since $v(t)$ is equal to $u$ up to finitely many coordinates and a multiplication by a constant, and $u\notin \ell^p$ for all $0 < p < 2$, and for $t = 1$ we have $v(t) = v\notin \ell^p, 0 < p < 2$ as well.
The only thing that is a tiny bit not obvious is continuity of $v(t)$ at $t = 1$, but this follows since for any vector $w\in \ell^2$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N(w, \epsilon)$ such that $\sum_{n > N} |w_n|^2 < \epsilon$.

Ah, this is far simpler. I was thinking we had to rotate to points with disjoint support before uniformly moving from one to the other. Forgot we could just alter coordinates one-by-one. I suppose this spared me of the effort needed to write down my approach then. +1

Thank you for your intersting argument.So this question gives an example of an infinite dimensional sphere with two complemented dense set each of them path connected..I doubt this could be hold in finite dimensional case

I wonder if  A is contractible too?

For the first question, yes, $S \setminus A$ is contractible. Rewrite the standard basis so that it is indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $U$ be the bilateral shift. Then $U$ is an isomorphism on $\ell^p$ for any $0 < p \leq 2$. Recall, from this paper, that $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \|x\|)e_0 + U(x)$ is a homeomorphism from the unit ball of $\ell^2$ onto itself without fixed point. From the geometric description of $\varphi$, contained in the proof of Theorem 1 of the cited paper, and using the facts that $e_0 \in \ell^p$ and $U$ is an isomorphism of $\ell^p$ for all $0 < p < 2$, it is not hard to see that $\varphi$ restricts to a homeomorphism from the unit ball of $\bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ (under the $\ell^2$ norm) to itself. Then $\psi$, which sends $x$ to the point at which the ray from $\varphi(x)$ to $x$ meets the unit sphere, is a retraction from the unit ball of $\bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ onto the unit sphere of $\bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ (i.e., $S \setminus A$). Thus, $S \setminus A$ is contractible, as $\Phi(x, t) = \psi(tx)$ is a homotopy between a constant map and the identity map on $S \setminus A$.

On second thought, I decided to still write down my approach to proving $A$ is path-connected despite Aleksei's wonderful (and simpler) answer, to ensure there is one complete answer.
For any $x \in A$, denote $x_e$ to be the part of $x$ supported on even indices and $x_o$ to be the part of $x$ supported on odd indices. Let $x, y \in A$. We first show that there is a path from $x$ to $x'$ in $A$, and from $y$ to $y'$ in $A$, s.t. $x'$ and $y'$ have disjoint supports.
Since $x \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$, we must have at least one of $x_e$ and $x_o$ is not in $\bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ either. The same holds for $y$. If $x_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ and $y_o \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$, then simply let $x' = \frac{x_e}{\|x_e\|}$. Now define,
$$f(t)_n = \begin{cases}
x_n &, \text{ if }n\text{ is even}\\
(1 - t)x_n &, \text{ if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
$$g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{\|f(t)\|}$$
It is then easy to verify that $g$ is a path from $x$ to $x'$ in $A$. Similarly, there is a path from $y$ to $y' = \frac{y_o}{\|y_o\|}$ in $A$. Clearly, $x'$ and $y'$ have disjoint supports. Similar arguments also apply when $x_o \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ and $y_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$.
Now, consider when $x_o \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ and $y_o \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$. The point here is we can first rotate $x$ to $x''$ s.t. $(x'')_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$, then apply the result of the previous paragraph. This can be easily achieved by,
$$f(t)_n = \begin{cases}
\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t)x_n + \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)x_{n+1} &, \text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\\
-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)x_{n-1} + \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t)x_n &, \text{ if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$
Then set $x'' = f(1)$. Since $(x'')_e$ is simply $x_o$ shifted one index forward, we have $(x'')_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$. $f(t)$ is simply rotation in each pair of adjacent coordinates, so it preserves the $\ell^2$ norm. Any rotation matrix is also both bounded below and above under $\ell^p$ norm for any $0 < p < 2$, so as $x \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$, $f(t) \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ either for any $t$. Thus, $f(t)$ is indeed a path in $A$. Now apply the result in the previous paragraph to reach the desired conclusion. The case where $x_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ and $y_e \notin \bigcup_{0 < p < 2} \ell^p$ can be proved similarly.
Now, it suffices to show that for $x, y \in A$ with disjoint supports, they can be connected by a path. Such a path is simply given by,
$$f(t) = \frac{tx + (1 - t)y}{\|tx + (1 - t)y\|}$$

I highly suspect $A$ is path-connected. It should be possible to “rotate” two elements of $A$ in $A$ so that their supports become disjoint, then just use a line segment (properly normalized) to connect the two. But I couldn’t figure out how to formalize this.

I  am  leaving  for  a  few  hours  I  will  come  back  here, thanks  again

To  be  honnest  I  doubt  even A is  connected  but I  have  no  idea  to  proof. Some  how  I am  curious  : which one  is  bigger  A  or  its complement??!!

befor  I read the  details, in the  linked paper  the  set $|x|\leq 1$ is  called sphere but the usual terminology is  ball  or  disk   I  think.  any  way in my question I  mean  the sphere the point of  unit  norm  not  less  than 1. But I guess your  argument  still  work, yes?

@AliTaghavi The linked paper called the unit ball “the closed solid unit sphere” and $S$ the “surface” of that. I’m aware of that, and yes, the argument in my answer works as is for $S$ being the unit sphere in the usual sense (norm exactly one). It’s just terminology differences.

@AliTaghavi In what sense you want to talk about being “bigger”? They have the same cardinality. They are both dense. I suspect they are both topologically speaking infinite-dimensional. And, as you already know, there’s no canonical way to define on a measure on $S$. I don’t see any other way to compare their sizes.

@AliTaghavi I figured out a proof that $A$ is path-connected. I’ll write a proof down shortly.

no matter of cardinality I care a kind of mrasur3 or density

I wondee if A is contractible too

@AliTaghavi I believe so. The path constructed in Aleksei’s answer is rather uniform in the starting point, so you can just combine those paths into a contraction of $A$ onto a single point. There are some technical details to check, but I’m reasonably sure it should work.

Ok   Thank  you.  BTW is  your argument capable of  being a  proof  of  contractibility. Any  way the  infinite  dimensional  sphere is  amazing: two  complemented  dense contractible  set!

@AliTaghavi My argument probably does not work to prove contractibility. The rotation part depends on whether the even or the odd part is not in $\ell^p$, so it’s sort of discontinuous.
